# How to change dataLabel style on render in Highcharts?

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

In the `render` method, I look for `dataLabels` that overlap each other and shift them up. But also for such `dataLabels` I want to change the background color and maybe some other styles. Here is my render:

```js
render: function () {
  const points = this.series[0].points;
  for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {

    if (i < points.length - 1) {
      const dataLabel1 = (points[i] as any).dataLabel
      const dataLabel2 = (points[i + 1] as any).dataLabel

      if ((dataLabel1.x + dataLabel1.width) > dataLabel2.x) {
        dataLabel1.attr({
          y: dataLabel1.y - (dataLabel1.height + 2),
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to change the styles like this:

```js
dataLabel1.options.style = {
  color: "white"
}
```

or like this:

```js
dataLabel1.options = {
  style: {
    backgroundColor: "Black"
  }
}
```

But it has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to overwrite the datalabel text style instead of using `dataLabel.attr()` method you need to use `dataLabel.css()`:

```js
dataLabel1.css({
  color: 'red'
})
```

And in case of changing the background it is generated as SVG rect so you need to change the fill attribute:

```js
dataLabel1.attr({
  y: dataLabel1.y - (dataLabel1.height + 2),
  fill: 'green',
});
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2rnko8t5/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `dataLabel1.css()` works, but adding `fill` to `attr()` doesn't work for me

Comment: Actually, it works, but requires to rerender the chart, didn't think of it right away